# CMAKE 3 binary package for PRECISE

Tags: 12.04, cmake

Does anyone know where this package would be available? I am looking to use it on Travis-CI so building from sources takes too long and is not an option.

a dpkg would suffice if you know where to find it.

Comment: Is it worth assuming that you examined the binary packages available at [http://www.cmake.org/](http://www.cmake.org/) and that they did not do what you wanted?

Comment: I tried them but they didn't work. I wasn't able to drop in replace the binaries. Probably me doing something wrong.

Comment: @vinipsmaker "Carneiro Last seen Nov 6 '14 at 13:45" … I believe that my work was for nothing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CMake 3.2.2 is available for Precise in this PPA:

[ppa:george-edison55/precise-backports [image: Launchpad logo]](https://launchpad.net/~george-edison55/+archive/precise-backports) ([Click here for instructions on using PPAs.](https://askubuntu.com/q/4983))

Comment: It fails to install, because required `cmake-data` package is missing. See https://travis-ci.org/techtonik/pyside2-setup/jobs/104572436

Comment: Ok. Adding `cmake-data` fixed the issue. Thanks! =)

Answer (score 4):

The question is a bit dated and there are now version 3.2. Therefore, I refer in my response to the latest version. The individual steps are also for version 3.1, it must be replaced only the filename. <sub>The Linux way: A folder is also a file ;)</sub>

---

Create a temporary folder

```
mkdir ~/cmake_tmp
```

Download the latest version [here](http://www.cmake.org/download/):

- 64-bit

  ```
  cd ~/cmake_tmp
  wget http://www.cmake.org/files/v3.2/cmake-3.2.2-Linux-x86_64.tar.gz
  ```
- 32-bit

  ```
  cd ~/cmake_tmp
  wget http://www.cmake.org/files/v3.2/cmake-3.2.2-Linux-i386.tar.gz
  ```

*The following steps use the 64-bit version*

Now install with:

```
tar xf cmake-3.2.2-Linux-x86_64.tar.gz
```

At last copy the files for a parallel installation, in addition to an other version in `/usr` with:

```
sudo cp -r cmake-3.2.2-Linux-x86_64/* /usr/local
```

- You can use the binary

To overwrite the files in `/usr`, use this command:

```
sudo cp -r cmake-3.2.2-Linux-x86_64/* /usr
```

***The use of the script is unnecessary as this only creates a directory with the content, which is also contained in the archive.***

Housekeeping:

```
rm -f ~/cmake_tmp
```

---

### How do I use which version?

If you have copied `cmake-3.2.2-Linux-x86_64/*` in the local folder `/usr/local` then you can decide which binary you want to use. Depending on the content of `$PATH`:

- My example:

  ```
  % echo $PATH
  /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
  ```

a specific binary is used. In my case the binary in `/usr/local/bin`. To use the binary in `usr/bin`, I have to specify the complete path, eg.:

```
/usr/bin/cmake
```

Comment: Upvoted this because I put me on the right track.

For the record CMake also provides an [installation script](http://www.cmake.org/files/v3.2/cmake-3.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh) next to the archive that makes these steps even simpler. Just call it with `--skip-license --prefix=/usr` and it works wonders.

Answer (score 1):

CMake 3.3.2, currently the newest version, is available in this PPA:

https://launchpad.net/~roblib/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

Answer (score -1):

You could download them from cake. com and extract them from the mouse menu, and follow the inot all ation file, and you could use these command to install it enter in the terminal this:

```
  sudo su <the sh files>
```

Or this.

```
  jhbuild <the installation file>
```

and this After any of the others.

```
  make <the cake installation file>
```

and to install jhbuild type this in.

```
  sudo apt-get install jhbuild
```

and after one of three upper type this in.

```
  make
```

and it might work fine this way.

Comment: Instead of cake.com you meant cmake.com...