# Is there a PPA offering CMake >= 3.2 for Ubuntu Precise?

Tags: 12.04, ppa, cmake

I'm trying to get cmake 3.2 or newer on travis-ci, which runs precise. Is there any PPA? I found `ppa:george-edison55/cmake-3.x` but it doesn't offer precise.

I found this question offering [manual installation steps](https://askubuntu.com/questions/544598/cmake-3-binary-package-for-precise), so if there's no existing PPA, I can use that.

Comment: you purposely asking 3.2 ? current version is 3.3.2

Comment: Daenyth, most 'new' toolchains are going to end up having to be made on newer systems, if only because older LTS sometimes has very little library support for newer software...

Comment: @Ravan 3.3 would be fine - updating

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CMAKE 3 binary package for PRECISE](http://askubuntu.com/questions/544598/cmake-3-binary-package-for-precise)

Answer (score 9):

*Update*

There is a PPA for Precise, see [@NathanOsman](https://askubuntu.com/users/5/nathan-osman) [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/679422/367165).

---

You could compile it yourself. The example below is for cmake 3.2.x. Check [here](http://cmake.org/download/) for the latest version, currently 3.3.2.

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
wget http://www.cmake.org/files/v3.2/cmake-3.2.2.tar.gz
tar xf cmake-3.2.2.tar.gz
cd cmake-3.2.2
./configure
make
```

and install

- with `checkinstall` for a installed deb package

  ```
  sudo apt-get install checkinstall
  sudo checkinstall
  ```

**OR**

- with `make install`

  ```
  sudo make install
  ```

Answer (score 9):

CMake 3.2.2 is available for Precise in this PPA:

[ppa:george-edison55/precise-backports [image: Launchpad logo]](https://launchpad.net/~george-edison55/+archive/precise-backports) ([Click here for instructions on using PPAs.](https://askubuntu.com/q/4983))